# does $f_n = |x|^{1 + 1/n} $ uniformly converge on $[-1,1]$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does $f_n = |x|^{1 + 1/n} $ converge uniformly to $|x| $ on $[-1,1] $ ?

I have tried to calculate (for $x \in[0,1]) $ $\sup|f_n(x) - f(x)| = \sup(x-x^{1 + 1/n} ) $  i miss calculated the $x_n $ that the sup occurs at, this is the answer :
the sup occurs at $x_n = \left(\dfrac{n}{1+n}\right)^n $ 
and this implies that $sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f_n(x) -f(x) | \to 0 $when $ n \to \infty $

Comment: Something like what you wrote about sup is right, with minor difference of detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $x\in[0,1]$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}x^{1+1/n}=x$.  Now, Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in [0,1]}\left|x^{1+1/n}-x\right|&=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-n}-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-n-1}\\\\
&=\frac1n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-n-1}\\\\
&\le \frac{1}{en}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $n>\frac{1}{e\epsilon}$.

Therefore, $x^{1+1/n}$ converges uniformly to $x$ for $x\in [0,1]$.

The analysis for $x\in [-1,0]$ proceed similarly.

Comment: Thanks, i have miss calculated the max points

Answer (score 2):

Note that it suffices to prove uniform convergence over $[0,1]$. Let $g_n(x)= f(x) - f_n(x)$. We have that $g_n \ge 0$, and if we draw the table of variations of $g_n$, we see that $g_n$ attains is maximum at the point $x = \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^n$. Hence,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \|g_n\|_{\infty} \le \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n \left( \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^n \right) = \lim \left( \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \right) = 0$$

So the convergence is uniform.